# Probability of minimum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An unbiased die is cast eight independent times. Let Y be the smallest of the eight numbers obtained. Find the pdf of Y. My solution: Bi (n=8, p=1/6) Please helpe on how to solve this one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We find for example the probability that the smallest number is equal to $3$.

The probability that the smallest is $\ge 3$ is the probability they are all $\ge 3$, which is $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^8$.

The probability that the smallest is $\ge 4 $ is the probability they are all $\ge 4$, which is $\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^8$.

So the probability the smallest is exactly $3$ is 
$$\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^8-\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^8.$$
The others are done the same way, except that equal to $1$ and equal to $6$ are easier.